# What's the mean of X when we have equations for Y1 and Y2?

Tags: probability, linear-transformations

Let Y1 = ((1/2)X^2) - 1 
and Y2 = ((1/2)X) -1
where X is a random variable whose mean is positive.
Moreover, we know that the mean of Y1 is 2, and the variance of Y2 is 0.5.

What's the mean of X?

I have no idea where to begin with this question. Anything helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what is given:
$$
\begin{array}{}
2 & = & \mathrm{E}\left[Y_{1}\right] & = & \mathrm{E}\left[ \frac{1}{2} X^{2} -1 \right] & = & \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{E}\left[X^{2}\right] - 1 \\
0.5 & = & \mathrm{Var} \left( Y_{2} \right) & = & \mathrm{Var} \left( \frac{1}{2} X - 1 \right) & = & \frac{1}{4}\mathrm{Var} \left( X \right).
\end{array}
$$
Therefore, we know the values for $\mathrm{Var}\left(X\right)$ and $\mathrm{E}\left[X^{2}\right]$. It can be shown that 
$$
\mathrm{Var}(X) = \mathrm{E}\left[X^{2}\right] - \mathrm{E}^{2}\left[X\right].
$$
It is said that the mean of $X$ is positive, so finally
$$
\mathrm{E}\left[X\right] = \sqrt{\mathrm{E}\left[X^{2}\right] - \mathrm{Var}\left(X\right)}.
$$

Comment: How do you transform Var(1/2X-1) to 1/4 Var(X)?

Comment: $$\begin{array}{rcl} Var\left(\frac{1}{2}X-1\right) & = & E[(\frac{1}{2}X-1-E[\frac{1}{2}X-1])^{2}]\\ &=&E[(\frac{1}{2}X-1-\frac{1}{2}E[X]+1)^{2}]\\ &=&E[(\frac{1}{2}(X-E[X]))^{2}]\\ &=&E[\frac{1}{4}(X-E[X])^{2}]\\ & = & \frac{1}{4}E[(X-E[X])^{2}]\\ &=& \frac{1}{4}Var(X).\end{array}$$ Moreover, for any random variable $W$ it is true that $$Var(aW+b) = a^{2} Var(W),$$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

Answer (score 0):

Given $Y_1 = \frac{1}{2}X^2-1$ and $Y_2 = \frac{1}{2}X-1$. Since the expectation operator is linear we obtain:
$$\mathbb{E}[Y_1] = \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{E}[X^2]-1 = 2,$$
and hence $\mathbb{E}[X^2] = 6$. On the other hand we have given that
$$\mbox{Var}[Y_2] = \mathbb{E}[Y_2^2]-(\mathbb{E}[Y_2])^2 = 0.5$$
To proceed, substitute $Y_2 = (1/2)X-1$ into the expression for the variance, simplify and use the fact that $\mathbb{E}[X^2] = 6$ to derive $\mathbb{E}[X]$.